Cannot GET /images/pottery1.jpg
I'm trying to display images on my Node.js server, but I'm getting the error

Cannot GET /images/pottery1.jpg

project folder/
  server.js
  public/
    index.html
    images/
      pottery1.jpg
      pottery2.jpg
      pottery3.jpg
      pottery4.jpg

I am using express.static method to defining the pictures directory
server.js
app.use(express.static('public'));

I go to the localhost:3000 page and the pottery pictures are not displayed

Also I changed the sequence of pottery number in index.html to be correct (pottery 1, pottery 2) pushed in github repo, after opening localhost:300 nothing changed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

That looks fine to me and matches the Express docs example. This doesn't appear to be reproducible

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

